# Distribute row contents based on avaiable height

Tags: html, css

I want my `.info` class fit with the available height and each of the 3 rows taking `33%` of that height. here is my code.

```css
div {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 310px;
  position: relative;
  border: .09rem solid rgb(36, 41, 46);
  border-radius: .3rem;
}

.avatar {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%
}

.avatar img {
  min-height: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  border: .09rem solid rgb(36, 41, 46);
}

.info {
  width: 70%;
  margin-right: .1rem;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="http://notavaiable.com" alt="not">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="row">
        <span>name</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span>17</span>
        <span>20</span>
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">location</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Please Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change your css a little. Namely:

- Assign `align-items: stretch` to `.content`;
- Assign `min-height: 150px` and `min-width: 100%` to `.avatar img`;
- Assign `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to `.info`;

And make a replacement for this selector:

```
div {
  display: block;
}
```

To this selector:

```
.info .row {
  flex: 1;
}
```

This rule sets the height of 1/3 to each `.row`.

```css
.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 310px;
  position: relative;
  border: .09rem solid rgb(36, 41, 46);
  border-radius: .3rem;
}

.avatar {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}

.avatar img {
  min-height: 150px;
  min-width: 100%;
  border: .09rem solid rgb(36, 41, 46);
}

.info {
  width: 70%;
  margin-right: .1rem;
  text-align: right; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.info .row {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="http://notavaiable.com" alt="not">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="row">
        <span>name</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span>17</span>
        <span>20</span>
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">location</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
here is your code if I understood correctly
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 310px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(36, 41, 46);
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.avatar {
  width: 30%;
}

.avatar img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(36, 41, 46);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.info {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.row {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" alt="not">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="row">
      <span>name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span>17</span>
      <span>20</span>
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">location</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and if you want to save size 150x150 for avatar, it can't be 30% of 310px